# dialog over lock incoming call screen

Tags: android, dialog, call, incoming-call

I want that both dialog and incoming call screen be clickable. I have tried different solutions from this site, but some works in some condtions and others don't. I want to create an app like true caller, I have called an activity from `BroadcastReceiver`. My code works perfectly when the screen is not locked because the incoming screen is not full screen. But when the screen is full screen the dialog activity appears for few milliseconds over the calling screen and then goes behind the calling screen.

Here is my code of my activity which I called from BroadcastReceiver

```
public class IncomingCallActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int MSG_ID_CHECK_TOP_ACTIVITY = 1;

private String userName;
private String TAG = IncomingCallActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Window wind;

private PowerManager powerManager;
private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

/*private ActivityManager mActivityManager;
private boolean mDismissed = false;*/

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    wind = this.getWindow();
    wind.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

    powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Lock");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming_call);
    userName = getIntent().getStringExtra(IncomingCallReceiver.NAME_KEY);

    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUsername);
    textView.setText(userName);

    final ImageView ivCancel = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivCancel);
    ivCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            wakeLock.release();
            IncomingCallActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     //Add Permissions in Manifest file and don't forget to check overlay permission
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW"/>

     //Create Class Level Variable  or as per requirement 

                WindowManager.LayoutParams mWindowsParams;
                WindowManager mWindowManager;
                View mDialogView;

    //initialize variable
 mWindowsParams =new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
mWindowManager=(WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

//Add Window on your event
 mWindowManager.addView(mDialogView, mWindowsParams);

//For Remove window

 if (mDialogView.getParent() != null) {
      try {
          mWindowManager.removeViewImmediate(mDialogView);
            } catch (Exception e) {

             }
        }
```

Comment: I have also tried this, it will make the incoming screen unclickable, I want both screens clickable.

Comment: Add same window param you will not face this issue .I am using same code for display pop up on incoming call.and try to add the dialog view as     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                  myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

           mDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.small_pop_up_layout,
                    null);

Comment: Yeah it worked with the given Params. A huge (great) thanks Gautam. I was struggling for long.

Comment: TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR is deprecated. any alternative?