# custom dialog box hides behind another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am new to android. Currently working on Caller Id app like 'truecaller'. I am showing call log screen and on click of Call log entry (which is linearlayout) I am calling Action_Call intent.

```
private View setList(int position, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View row = inf.inflate(R.layout.liststyle, parent, false);

        TextView tvName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvNameMain);
        final TextView tvNumber = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvNumberMain);
        TextView tvTime = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        TextView tvDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        //TextView tvType = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvType);
        ImageView tvImageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvTypeImage);

        final LinearLayout callLogLayout = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.callLogLayout);
        callLogLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final int REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 1;
                String Number = tvNumber.getText().toString();
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( row.getContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( CallLogActivity.this, new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE  },
                            REQUEST_PHONE_CALL );
                }
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Number));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });
```

Screen looks like below.

[image]

My Problem is 'Custom Caller ID Dialog box' which I am showing when outgoing call get started gets stick to above screen (call log screen) and not showing it on Actual Call screen.

When I click on Call Log entry below screen pops up.

[image]

When I click end call button then I can see custom dialog box.

[image]

OnCallStateChanged

```
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
            if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                isIncoming = false;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                contactName = CallSmsDetector.retrieveContactName(context, savedNumber);
                // CallSmsDetector.startRecording(context);
                mCallListener.onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, contactName);
                //mCallListener.onOutgoingCallEnded(context,savedNumber,callStartTime,contactName);
            } else {
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                contactName = CallSmsDetector.retrieveContactName(context, savedNumber);
                // CallSmsDetector.startRecording(context);
                // mCallListener.onIncomingCallAnswered(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, contactName);
                //mCallListener.onIncomingCallEnded(context,savedNumber,callStartTime,contactName);
            }
            break;
```

OnOutgoingCallStarted

```
public void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start, String contactName)
        {
            //popup(contactName, number);
            cName = contactName;
            Log.e("onOutgoingCallStarted","onOutgoingCallStarted");
            if(contactName==""){
                Intent i=new Intent(ctx,PopupActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("DATAPASSED",number);
                Log.e("number",number);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);

            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("Contact number",contactName);
                Intent i=new Intent(ctx,PopupActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("DATAPASSED",contactName);
                i.putExtra("Number",number);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);

            }

            Log.e("outgoing call started", number);

        }
```

Does it require delay? I am not getting any clue.

**UPDATE** Whenever I put breakpoint in code, surprisingly it works perfectly.

I have even tried to put delay but no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have a **context problem** . I have faced this issue many times where I passed in `getActivity()` and the popup menu appeared behind my `activity`. I think if you change the first line in setList() to

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
```

should work fine.
Try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried what you have suggested. Unfortunately, its not working. Now Call screen stays behind and Call log screen and pop up appears in front. I want Pop up to be appear along with Call screen.

Comment: Are you using elevation in your xml layout?? If you are supporting below 21. Use cardview. Ill look into your code again...

Comment: @Rakesh Yadav I saw your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686421/dialog-over-lock-incoming-call-screen   I believe you have also developed app like trucaller. If you can look at my problem and suggest any solution, that would be very helpful. I could not comment on your question as I have 49 reputations and commenting required 50. :(  hence tagging you here.